# Built In voltage drop across a pnn+ device

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Will the net built-in potential of an p+,n,n+ device having two junctions(1.) that of p+ and n and 2.) that of n and n+ simply be the addition of the built in potentials of the junctions?

Comment: What potential are you expecting at the n-n+ "junction"?

Comment: When n and n+ sides will be connected together, there will be diffusion of electrons from the n+ side to the n side leaving behind positively charged donor ions. At thermal equilibrium, the induced electric field and diffusion will cancel out each other. So, won't there be a net voltage drop across n and n+?

Comment: Where are the Fermi levels in the $n$ vs $n+$?

Comment: Below Ec and above Emid. (Considering a non-degenerate semiconductor). In the case of n+, the fermi will be more closer to the Ec than in the case of n.

Comment: Consider a uniformly doped $n$-type sample. Perturb $n$ (or $p$) somehow, even by magic. What happens now? Hint: Shockley-Reid-Hall should come to mind.

Comment: I have no idea about the Shockley read hall theory.